AspectJ Internal Error: unable to add stackmap attributes. Unsupported class file major version 61
I have the following Kotlin application
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Kotlin:       1.9.22
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          17.0.8 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.8+9-LTS-211)
OS:           Mac OS X 14.0 x86_64

And I always see an error during using ./gradlew test-unit -Pci but project runs well and build OK too:
Gradle Test Executor 8 STANDARD_ERROR
    AspectJ Internal Error: unable to add stackmap attributes. Unsupported class file major version 61
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
        at aj.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:195)
        at aj.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:176)
        at aj.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:162)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.asm.StackMapAdder.addStackMaps(StackMapAdder.java:42)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyClassGen.getJavaClassBytesIncludingReweavable(LazyClassGen.java:764)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.getClassFilesFor(BcelWeaver.java:1464)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveAndNotify(BcelWeaver.java:1426)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1196)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.getWovenBytes(WeavingAdaptor.java:551)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(WeavingAdaptor.java:387)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj.preProcess(Aj.java:116)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:51)
        at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:244)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:541)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.loadClass(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:168)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.access$100(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.execute(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.execute(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:94)

I think there are some problems with my dependencies in project but I haven't found anything unusual and I've tried to add some new dependencies like
testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-console-standalone:1.10.2")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")

but it did not help me out too
Can you please give a piece of advice - what should I add to my project?
